# How can I write WPF efficiently?

Tags: wpf

When I first learned about Microsoft's then-new framework for developing desktop applications, WPF, I thought that one of the biggest benefits of it would be its efficiency.  After all, I already know what the GUI controls and elements were that I wanted to use--I just have to slap them all on the page and then wire up all my bindings right, and I'll be done.  After that, I learned about the MVVM pattern, which promised clean separation of concern within my WPF app.

I thought this was going to be great!  I got into creating several different admin and data entry WPF apps with my team at work, and thus I began to crank out working software with robust but simple GUIs, right?

Not so fast, there, cowboy coder. My experience is that writing WPF is S-L-O-W.

Well, at least the way I do it.  You see, after I have a picture of my GUI on a whiteboard, I code up the XAML with the controls that I want.  This part, as expected, is fast--laying out the whole of a window is pretty quick. After that, its all the little stuff you want these elements to do takes awhile. I always seem to want to make this text bold in some cases; show a red error box in these other cases.

Then things unravel: this binding isn't working right over here--I have to write a converter and adjust the layout for the right values. Whoops, I forgot that extra NotifyPropertyChanged there. Oh, and I want to use a different template in this state vs. that, so I have to figure out what I can use to swap the templates in certain situation.  This data is coming in asynchronously, so I need to make sure the right thing is happening on the right thread and that Property gets NotifyChanged as well.  Crap, when I maximize my window, it doesn't stretch like I thought it would--must be because its container height isn't defined, but I don't want to define that, so I have to make it stretch in its parent.  Oh, now I really want to make a user control out of this stuff over here, so I better implement some dependency properties...

On and on I go, spending hours and days on stuff that just feels so small and minor. I soon resort to cutting usability features and look-and-feel enhancements because this is taking just too darn long.

Does anyone have any tips or principles I need to try in order to write WPF efficiently?

Comment: Originally asked this on my blog ( http://www.szalapski.com/2011/04/how-can-i-write-wpf-efficiently.html ), but didn't get a response. :) By the way, I realize this is a "discussion" kind of question, but indeed I am really seeking actual answers. Hope that is okay.

Comment: WPF and MVVM have a steep, ongoing learning curve; these are rapidly evolving techniques and technologies, with best practices and support tools still somewhat in their infancy.  I've gotten to the point now where I am faster with WPF than I was with WinForms, with better results, but it took well over a year to get there, owing in a large part to the utility classes I've accumulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own library, or find an existing one.

WPF is great, but out of the box it is missing some things that would make coding faster. I got tired of writing the same things repeatedly, so I ended up creating my own library full of things like converters, visual tree helpers, attached properties, custom controls, etc., and since then, my development time has sped up considerably.

In addition to my own library, I've also started using Microsoft's [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) and Galasoft's [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). Both contain useful objects that I use all the time and are better than what I could code on my own. (Most used are `NotificationObject` from Prism, `RelayCommand` from MVVM Light Toolkit, and `EventAggregator` or `Messenger` from either one depending on the project, etc.)

Another thing I've done to speed up coding time is to take advantage of Visual Studio's macros. For example, to create a property with Change notification, I write the private property, hit `Ctrl+E`, `Ctrl+R` which generates the public version, then run a macro which automatically sets up the `PropertyChanged` notification in the setter method.

I almost never change the setter methods from the default macro'd one, and instead use the `PropertyChanged` event to handle any changes that should occur on the setter. This not only makes it easier to track application flow, but also greatly reduces the time I used to waste browsing through my public properties to alter a setter method.

Comment: Following your suggestions, instead of using macros, Visual Studio 2010 will be better with a guidance pack.

Comment: I think this answer is best so far, because it gave me specific examples as well as pointing to a bigger general picture.  Thanks, @Rachel!

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things that have saved a lot of time for me:

- Use `DockPanel` as your default panel for layout unless you have a good reason not to.
- Keep a folder full of useful classes:  a `ViewModelBase` class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, a `RelayCommand` class, etc. There's no need to get fancy and try to make this a separate assembly that you build into your project; just write reasonably good implementations and copy/paste them into your new projects.
- Get Resharper and use it.  Use templates for creating dependency properties, properties that do change notification, and commands.
- Find or build a good library for asynchronous task management.

I find that even for very simple applications I get more done faster with WPF than I did with Windows Forms.  For applications that aren't very simple, there's absolutely no comparison.

For the most part, WPF applications are a lot of work to develop because it's harder to make the case for cutting out UI features.  You can't just say, "Oh, that's not possible," because it probably *is* possible (whatever "it" is).

Comment: +1 I think the last paragraph is the golden part.  You have a tendency to want to do more and fancier stuff with WPF than with WinForms, and that's the reason it ends up taking longer.

Comment: "Oh, and I want to use a different template in this state vs. that, so I have to figure out what I can use to swap the templates in certain situation," that's a pretty high-quality problem to be able to have.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the right answer isn't for WPF at all, but it can fit what you're looking for.

Most of the times, when you want to leverage a new technology there's a time while you're not efficient, productive and your solutions aren't that impressive, innovative or just doesn't look like others.

What will give you more efficiency is working with WPF itself.

It's more about project management topics than programming. After finishing some project, your team and you should go to some room and discuss:

- Success stories.
- Problems during development.
- Pros and cons.
- Fails in the application architecture.
- Communication problems within the team and customer.
- ... and so on.

If everyone shares their knowledge, project manager or team leader does a good job documenting each project story, finally everyone will have a "know-how".

In addition, it's important that you won't need to reinvent the wheel for every new project: if some pattern worked fine, do the same way next time, even if it's not the best way of doing it. And try to enhance it, if possible.

Design patterns, technologies, paradigms, languages, companies, colleagues and nothing are a silver bullet: Microsoft said WPF is a step-forward in Windows client developments, and it is that: a more modern approach to provide shinny user interfaces and a programming paradigm that fits nowadays' desired approaches, easing the relation between coders and designers, as WPF has XAML, which allows not only separation of concerns, but separation of professionals by area (designers, UI programmers, business programmers, ...).

Finally, as I said above, WPF won't be your silver bullet: learn from your own success and read a lot, see sample applications, download open source solutions, listen your colleagues, drink a coffee and, after all, after some headaches, some day in the near future, you'll leverage these technologies (and many others).

**EDIT**

I'd like to add that a good way of using the know-how is creating a Visual Studio guidance pack, so you can automate a lot of tasks like creating managers, views, models and other things just in the way your team would do by hand.

For example, you can create a guidance pack for a WPF CRM-like application and you can automate module creation. When you want to add a new module, guidance pack starts a process which adds all the necessary classes to start development this new module, and it can create a sample form already associated with a navigation manager, controller or whatever (it's just an example).

Guidance pack and T4 would be both good tools for automating tedious or repetitive tasks in everyday's tasks:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631854.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have been using WPF since 2008 and can honestly say to do it right and clean does take more time than the same thing in WinForms would take to develop.  I have written a lot more WPF than Winforms.  That being said - if I need a simple internal utility - it is ALWAYS Winforms.  If I have something forward facing to a client - it is always WPF.  Why?  Winforms are cheap and dirty and you get a lot for free.  What you don't get is the fit and polish that WPF can provide. The flexibility with WPF does come at a cost - but in the longer run it's worth it for public facing software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes WPF is a hurdle but it also has rewards.  You are on the right track with a design pattern such as MVVM.  Sounds like you have not even gotten to the "rewards" of dependency properties or event bubbling.  But the control over the UI is great.  Almost everything is a content control.  In forms I was always writing custom controls to get the UI I wanted.  In WFP I have never had to write a custom control for UI and doubt I ever will.  The syntax is new but it is compact - I rewrote a Form app in WPF and the WPF has 1/3 the lines and more features.  Read a whole book on WPF just to get grounded - I like PRO WPF in C# 2010.  You could also say LINQ is complex but man does it do a lot in just a few key strokes.  WPF is not something you just pick up on the fly as you next application.